# Getting 'Internal Server Error' when accessing JSPs. Servlets ok

Tags: jsp, websphere

I have just installed WS 7 on our stage server. The test server was done some months ago. I have deployed the same applications to stage as on test.

One application is causing me problems. I call the login servlet but the result is an 'Internal Server Error' message. From my logs I can see that the servlet processed the log in successfully and redirects to a JSP. That is the last message. I can find no further info in any of the other standard out/err logs.

I have tried creating a simple JSP containing only HTML - same error. If I rename the file to test.html, it displays correctly. The plugin configuration appears to be identical with the one on the test server (where everything works)

Ideas anyone?

**http_plugin.log**

```
[Tue Sep 21 14:06:02 2010] 00000bd4 00002430 - ERROR: ws_common: websphereGetStream: socket error conditions pending
[Tue Sep 21 14:06:02 2010] 00000bd4 00002430 - ERROR: ws_common: websphereExecute: Failed to create the stream
[Tue Sep 21 14:06:02 2010] 00000bd4 00002430 - ERROR: ws_common: websphereHandleRequest: Failed to execute the transaction to 'server1'on host 'SRVxyz'; will try another one
[Tue Sep 21 14:06:03 2010] 00000bd4 00002430 - ERROR: ws_common: websphereGetStream: socket error conditions pending
[Tue Sep 21 14:06:03 2010] 00000bd4 00002430 - ERROR: ws_common: websphereExecute: Failed to create the stream
[Tue Sep 21 14:06:03 2010] 00000bd4 00002430 - ERROR: ws_common: websphereHandleRequest: Failed to execute the transaction to 'server1'on host 'SRVxyz'; will try another one
[Tue Sep 21 14:06:03 2010] 00000bd4 00002430 - ERROR: ws_common: websphereWriteRequestReadResponse: Failed to find an app server to handle this request
[Tue Sep 21 14:06:03 2010] 00000bd4 00002430 - ERROR: ESI: getResponse: failed to get response: rc = 2
[Tue Sep 21 14:06:03 2010] 00000bd4 00002430 - ERROR: ws_common: websphereHandleRequest: Failed to handle request
```

Comment: You suspect the error is with the HTTP Plugin? Access the Web Container directly (and by pass the Web Server) to see if you are able to access your JSPs. What is your login servlet? (is that the FORM Based Login or a custom login servlet that you use). Is the login servlet making a round trip (back to the browser and then to the JSP) or is it performing a server side call to the JSP. In the case of the latter there is no involvement from HTTP plug in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is now solved.

The installation process created a default server. I had ignored this thinking that it doesn't matter. I removed the server and regenerated the plug-in config and my app works fine.